# Why are my equal strings not equal?

Tags: bash, expect

I found lot of same problems, but no solution help with mine.

listingInOrder.sh

```
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set dir [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set N [lindex $argv 3]
spawn ssh $user@pool$N.physik.hu-berlin.de ls -1tr $dir | tail -1
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
interact
```

mainfile.sh

```
filelocal=`ls -1tr $localdir | tail -1`
fileremote=`expect listingInOrder.sh $user $remotedir $password $N | tail -1`
if [[ "$filelocal" != "$fileremote" ]]; then
   echo "not equal"
   echo "$filelocal"
   echo "$fileremote"
fi
```

But the output is:

```
not equal
blatt3A2.m
blatt3A2.m
```

So the names are equal. What is the problem here?

Comment: That's not `bash`, it looks like an `Expect` script.

Comment: There's probably some extra whitespace in one of the variables. Try `echo "|$filelocal|"` and `echo "|$fileremote|"` so you can see where the values end.

Comment: @Barmar The first file is an Expect script, but the problem is in the bash file. |$...| gives this output `not equal
|blatt3A2.m|
|blatt3A2.m` I dont really know, what it means and, didn't know how to google this command. How do I proceed? Sorry, I'm new to bash

Comment: That shows it - there's a space at the end of `$fileremote`. Remove the space before comparing.

Comment: ...so your strings _aren't_ equal in the first place, because one has trailing whitespace, making the title of this question misleading.

Comment: Also, don't use `ls` programatically. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (...and if you weren't using password authentication, you wouldn't need to use `expect`, and would have gotten yourself into a lot less complexity here in the first place. RSA keys are not just more secure for situations where you need stored credentials, they're easier to work with as well).

Comment: For the record, if you want to read a remote filename: `ssh hostname "printf '%s\0' /path/to/directory/*"` will give you contents in a completely unambiguous NUL-delimited format, which can then be read with `IFS read -r -d ''`. (You can't safely use newline delimiters, because UNIX filenames can contain newlines within their text).

Comment: BTW, a better way to see if the strings were equal: `printf '%q\n' "$filelocal" "$fileremote"` would print them in a format that showed hidden characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. Somehow a \r was at the end of the String.

```
$ HEXVAL=$(xxd -pu <<< "$fileremote")
$ echo "$HEXVAL"
```

gave me the following output of the string as hex:

```
626c6174743341322e6d0d0a
```

And the 0d0a revealed itself as a \r.

```
sed $'s/\r//'
```

trimmed the string and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space at the end of `$fileremote`:

```
fileremote=`expect listingInOrder.sh $user $remotedir $password $N | tail -1`
fileremote=${fileremote% }
```